# Splash screen Error default image size is too big

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to display SplashScreen in my App. The code is the same that all tutorials or documentations but my problem is with icon, i put the default icon from mipmap but it looks like this
[image]

when i use any pic or icon is the same, how can i control the size?, because the default icon has the correct size.
The code

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" /><!-- color de fondo -->
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" /> <!-- imagen centrada -->
</item>
```

style.xml

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@mipmap/ic_launcher</item>
</style>
```

Activity

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_name);`

Comment: the xml is drawable is not layout